# Redirect output from local machine to a file on remote machine

Tags: bash, ssh, command-line, io-redirection

I want to save the output of a command I am executing in my bash shell of my local Ubuntu machine to a file in the remote machine.

The idea is to execute `ls` on my local machine:

```
ls >> file_on_remote_machine
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Depends on how you authenticate on the remote machine. A common arrangement is `ls | ssh remote 'cat >file'`; but there are many other remote access protocols, ranging from passwordless `netcat` to various mechanisms involving multiple protocols, often over HTTPS these days. Not really a programming  question anyway

Answer (score 3):

```bash
ls | ssh remote 'cat > output.txt'
```

should do.

Answer (score 0):

If the remote machine is an NFS file server and the local machine has mounted a disk from the remote machine, then

```
ls > /path/to/nfs/mounted/directory/file.txt
```

would accomplish the action you ask.  I'm aware this is probably more complex than you are looking for, but there are variations on the idea, such as using fuse+sshfs to do the equivalent through an ssh/sftp session rather than NFS.  ([Here's one tutorial on using sshfs like this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh), but there are other tutorials as well)